# What is Pantone Cyan used for?

Tags: color, print-design, pantone

What is the difference between cyan and Pantone Cyan Special Color?

Answer (score 5):

Cyan is one of the four primaries used in CMYK, or four-color process printing.  Cyan is NOT used in formulation of any PANTONE spot color.

The shading of Cyan is defined under ISO 2846-1.

PANTONE CYAN refers to Pantone's representation of Cyan, which is found in the following products only:

- PANTONE COLOR BRIDGE
- PANTONE CMYK COLOR GUIDE

Comment: Hey John, welcome to GD.SE! We generally [dissuade users from using signatures](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), but I encourage you to register and add your affiliation with Pantone to your profile!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, John. And welcome to the community. I hope you can stick around and help us with ink questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply Pantone's officially approved formulation for cyan.